# How to make this code work well with Queue?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I have a little doubt if one could solve my issue, and create successful communication between threads.

First example and this is how it should be working, but does not work well:

```
import Queue,threading,time

class th(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,q):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.q = q
        self.t = time

    def run(self):
        for i in range(5):
            self.q.put(i)
            self.t.sleep(0.5) # <----------
        self.q.put('end')

class main(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = Queue.Queue()
        self.thread = th(self.q)
        self.thread.setDaemon(True)
        self.thread.run()
        self.call()
    def call(self):
        while True:
            recv = self.q.get();
            if recv == 'end':
                break
            else:
                print recv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = main()
    root.call()
```

In this example, all printed at the same time:
0,1,2,3,4

Second example:

```
import Queue,threading,time

class th(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,q):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self);
        self.q = q
        self.t = time

    def run(self):
        for i in range(5):
            self.q.put(i) # <------ no sleep()
        self.q.put('end')

class main(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = Queue.Queue()
        self.thread = th(self.q)
        self.thread.setDaemon(True)
        self.thread.run()
        self.call()
    def call(self):
        while True:
            recv = self.q.get()
            if recv == 'end':
                break
            else:
                print recv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = main()
    root.call()
```

the code is printed as it has to
0,
1
2
3
4

one to one

is there any way that the `sleep` function in the same way?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to call the [`run`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.run) method on a thread directly. Call [`start`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start) instead, which will kick off the child thread, which will in turn run the `run` method.

Your current code is essentially single threaded, since the `run` call does the work of the child thread in the parent instead. The child thread is never actually started! (You're also calling your `main.call` method twice, which I'd expect to block or raise an exception, but that's a separate issue.)

Answer (score 0):

sorry, it was something very simple, really simple, just had to replace

```
self.thread.run()
```

by

```
self.threat.start()
```

Comment: Are you *sure* that's what you want to replace it with? You rarely solve any problems by starting to threaten yourself... ;)